# LDAP to Active Directory on GlassFish works, but still seeing javax.naming.PartialResultException

Tags: active-directory, glassfish, ldap

Using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1, thrown the web admin console, I created a security realm (Configurations -> server-config -> Security -> Realms) as follows:

```
Realm Name: MyLdapRealm
Class Name: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm
JAAS Context: ldapRealm
Directory: ldap://<server>:389
Base DN: dc=<company>,dc=com
Assign Groups: Domain Users
```

with the following additional properties

```
search-bind-dn: <admin>@<company>.com
search-bind-password: <password>
search-filter: (&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))
group-search-filter: (&(objectCategory=group)(member=%d))
referrals: follow
```

Then I added the JVM option (Configurations -> server-config -> JVM Settings -> JVM Options):

```
-Djava.naming.referral=follow
```

My web.xml has

```
...
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Security</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Protected</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>Protected</role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyLdapRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
...
```

And my sun-web.xml has

```
  ...
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>Protected</role-name>
    <group-name>Domain Users</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  ...
```

When I access any of the pages in the protected path, I get the default login prompt from the browser and I am able to authenticate and view the page. However, my server log shows:

```
WARNING: SEC1106: Error during LDAP search with filter [(&(objectCategory=group)(member=CN=<name>,OU=<a>,OU=<b>,OU=<c>,dc=<company>,dc=com))].
WARNING: SEC1000: Caught exception.
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'dc=<company>,dc=com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2794)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.getNextBatch(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:129)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMoreImpl(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:198)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapNamingEnumeration.hasMore(LdapNamingEnumeration.java:171)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm.groupSearch(LDAPRealm.java:702)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm.findAndBind(LDAPRealm.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule.authenticate(LDAPLoginModule.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:117)
    at com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.login(AppservPasswordLoginModule.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:512)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:453)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:168)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1326)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

WARNING: SEC1106: Error during LDAP search with filter [(&(objectclass=groupofuniquenames)(objectclass=*groupofurls*))].
WARNING: SEC1000: Caught exception.
javax.naming.PartialResultException: Unprocessed Continuation Reference(s); remaining name 'dc=<company>,dc=com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2820)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2794)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1826)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1749)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:368)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:338)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:321)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:248)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm.dynamicGroupSearch(LDAPRealm.java:647)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm.findAndBind(LDAPRealm.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LDAPLoginModule.authenticate(LDAPLoginModule.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.PasswordLoginModule.authenticateUser(PasswordLoginModule.java:117)
    at com.sun.appserv.security.AppservPasswordLoginModule.login(AppservPasswordLoginModule.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor360.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:240)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.login(LoginContextDriver.java:153)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:512)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.authenticate(RealmAdapter.java:453)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:168)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1326)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Why am I getting this stack trace in the server log? Why does it not recognize that I have the java.naming.referral JVM option set to follow? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've found here:
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-4769

> The REFERRAL flag can be set by passing "java.naming.referral=follow"
>   to the LDAP Realm options.

It works for me. Property "java.naming.referral" is defined in javax.naming.Context.REFERRAL